# Colors in Curses

Tags: python, curses

Im trying to add colors to my curses output. However the challenge is that the text is being printed via a single long str i.e self.all_results. Is there any way add color to a single part of the string.

```
def main(self,stdscr):
    x,y = 0,0 # size of the window
    xx,yy = 50,200  # where to place window - up,across
    pad = curses.newpad(150,150) # nlines, ncols
    pad_pos = 0
    exit = False

    pad.addstr(4,0,str(self.all_results))

    while not exit:
        sleep(0.2)
        if self.timer != None:
            if time() - start > self.timer:
                self.stop = True
                break

        pad.addstr(0,0,str(self.format_results()))
        pad.refresh(pad_pos,0, x,y, xx,yy)

        cmd = stdscr.getch()
        stdscr.nodelay(1)

        if cmd != -1:
            pad.refresh(pad_pos,0, x,y, xx,yy)
            if len(self.format_results().split('\n')) > 100:
                if  cmd == curses.KEY_DOWN:
                    if pad_pos < len(self.format_results())+1:
                        pad_pos += 1
                    try:
                        pad.refresh(pad_pos,0, x,y, xx,yy)
                    except curses.error:
                        pass
                elif cmd == curses.KEY_UP:
                    if pad_pos != 0:
                        pad_pos -= 1
                    try:
                        pad.refresh(pad_pos,0, x,y, xx,yy)
                    except curses.error:
                        pass
```

Comment: How to add color to part of string depends upon how to choose which part of the string to color. Is it by offset into the string? By the content of the string? By location on the screen?

Comment: The string much like... 'probe1 | NY | ERROR\nprobe1 | NY | OK'
I want ERROR in red and OK in green.,

Comment: Sure. Split the string into the parts you want coloured and you don't want coloured. Call `pad.attron` and `pad.attroff` around the calls to `pad.addstr` for the parts you want coloured.

Comment: I wrote a simple curses wrapper called [cusser](https://github.com/getcuia/cusser) that does exactly that (as per @RossRidge's strategy above) and understands embedded ANSI escape codes. The API is pretty much the same as standard curses, so you don't have to change anything.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `re` to split the string up and then use non-`x,y` form of `addstr`, specifiying the color for each portion.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import curses
from curses.wrapper import wrapper
import re


def addstr_colorized(win, y, x, s):
    colors = {'OK': curses.COLOR_GREEN, 'ERROR': curses.COLOR_RED}
    win.move(y, x)
    pattern = r'({0:s})'.format(
        '|'.join(r'\b{0:s}\b'.format(word) for word in colors.keys()))
    s = re.split(pattern, s)
    for s in s:
        win.addstr(s, curses.color_pair(colors.get(s, 0)))


def main(stdscr):
    curses.init_pair(curses.COLOR_RED,
                     curses.COLOR_RED,
                     curses.COLOR_BLACK)
    curses.init_pair(curses.COLOR_GREEN,
                     curses.COLOR_GREEN,
                     curses.COLOR_BLACK)

    addstr_colorized(stdscr,
                     4,
                     0,
                     "This line is OK.\nBut there is an ERROR in this line\n")
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getch()


wrapper(main)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used to accomplish it (not too pretty but it was fine for what I was doing).

You simply define your colour pairs somewhere ie:

```
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_BLUE, curses.COLOR_GREEN);
```

Then just call the function with a message containing colourN[str] where N is the colour pair num and str is the part of the string you want coloured.

For example:

```
addStrColour(stdscr, 0, "This is an example message, colour1[This is coloured using colour pair 1!!!] and now we have normal text again");
```

This is the function:

```
def addstrColour(stdscr, pos, message):
  #Split messages based on colour components
  newMes = re.split("(colour\d\[.*?\])", message);

  totalOut = 0;

  for line in newMes:
    m = re.match("colour(\d{1})\[(.*)\]", line);
    if m:
      colourPairNum = int((m.groups()[0]));

      stdscr.addstr(pos, totalOut, m.groups()[1], curses.color_pair(colourPairNum));
      totalOut += len(m.groups()[1]);
    else:
      stdscr.addstr(pos, totalOut, line);
      totalOut += len(line);
```